# Prove if $T : V\to U$ is linear, then the restriction$ T : \ker$⊥ $T \to$ range($T$) is one-to-one.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone prove this or point me in the right direction?
If T : V → U is linear, then the restriction T : ker⊥
T → range(T) is
one-to-one.

Comment: What is denoted $\ker \bot T$?

Comment: You mean the orthogonal complement of $kerT$? $(kerT)^{\perp}$?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Injection: Assume $x,y\in(\mathrm{Ker}T)^\perp$ and $Tx=Ty$. Then $T(x-y)=0$ or equivalently $x-y\in \mathrm{Ker}T$. But $x-y\in \mathrm{Ker}T$ implies $x-y=0$.

Surjection: For any $z\in\mathrm{ran}T$, there exists $x\in V$ such that $Tx=z$. Because $x=x_1+x_2$ for some $x_1\in \mathrm{Ker}T$ and $x_2\in(\mathrm{Ker}T)^\perp$, we know $Tx_1=z$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the concept of quotient space, $\ker T^\bot\simeq\operatorname{coker} T \overset{\text{def}}{=}V/\ker T$, and by the *First isomorphism theorem*,
$$V/\ker T\simeq\operatorname{Im}T. $$